# Why Append in jquery not working?

Tags: jquery, html, append

I want to append HTML code using jquery append function, but it's not working.

I want to append **`</div><div class="item">`** using this jquery code

```
$(this).before('</div> <div class="item">');
```

but it append `<div class="item"></div>`
Suggest me any best solution.

Comment: You need to append a complete, valid, HTML fragment, to an HTML element. jQuery is trying its best to obtain a valid fragment from what you've supplied.

Comment: Any solution to append this type </div> <div class="item">

Comment: append as a string not as HTML

Comment: @HarshPatel That would be a hack, just deferring (and adding to) the problem(s).

Answer (score 2):

The DOM is a tree structure of objects, not text like HTML. If you want to split the contents of a `div` into two parts, you can't just insert markup to do that, you have to create a new div and move the child nodes from the original into it that you want moved.

For instance, if you wanted everything before `this` in that code to be moved to a new div:

```
// Create an insert the div
var div = $("<div></div>").addClass("item");
div.insertBefore(this);
// Move `this` and all following siblings into it
var $this = $(this);
div.append($this.add($this.nextAll()));
```

*(There are more concise ways to do it, but they're not as clear to the beginner.)*

Live Example:

```js
$(".item").on("click", "div", function() {
    // Create an insert the div
    var div = $("<div></div>").addClass("item");
    div.insertBefore(this);
    // Move `this` and all following siblings into it
    var $this = $(this);
    div.append($this.add($this.nextAll()));
});
```

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<p>Click a line below to move it and the ones following it into a new div:</p>
<div class="item">
  <div>Line 1</div>
  <div>Line 2</div>
  <div>Line 3</div>
  <div>Line 4</div>
  <div>Line 5</div>
  <div>Line 6</div>
  <div>Line 7</div>
  <div>Line 8</div>
  <div>Line 9</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: *(Doh! If you see `before` above, hit refresh. Should be `insertBefore`.)*